# split column value into multiple columns in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data into table like this:

[image]

I want the output like this:

[image]

how we can achive this with orace sql statment.Kindly assist.

Comment: any help? I tried LISTAGG and REGEXP_SUBSTR functions but not able to achive this.kindly suggest

Comment: Can you provide the DDL Statement for same in the question?

Comment: create table test1(ID number(50),comp varchar2(250));

Comment: please use text data rather than images in order people easily to reproduce your scenario. Some people may not see the images due to being behind the firewall. Btw, the current images are son tiny to read. Moreover, the question contains no efforts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one option; not dynamic at all as you'll have to know how many items there are so that you could adjust the *final query*. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id, component) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1, '|TD-2-2720A-NVE-C:2|TD-2-2720A-TPM-C:2|TD-PREM-NLSAS-01-PR:480|TD-ONTAP-NLSAS-01-PR:480' from dual union all
  4     select 2, '|TD-2-A220A-TPM-C:2|DD-FLASH-PREM-01-PR:115|DD-FLASH-ONTAP-01-PR:115'                    from dual union all
  5     select 5, '|TD-2-2650A-NVE-C:2|TD-2-2650A-TPM-C:2'                                                  from dual
  6    ),
```

---

```
  7  temp as
  8    -- split each component into rows, separated by the pipe character
  9    (select id,
 10       column_value cv,
 11       regexp_substr(component, '[^|]+', 1, column_value) comp
 12     from test cross join
 13       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                           connect by level <= regexp_count(component, '\|')
 15                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16    )
 17  -- final result
 18  select id,
 19    max(case when cv = 1 then substr(comp, 1, instr(comp, ':') - 1) end) as comp_1,
 20    max(case when cv = 1 then regexp_substr(comp, '\d+$')           end) as cnt_1,
 21    --
 22    max(case when cv = 2 then substr(comp, 1, instr(comp, ':') - 1) end) as comp_2,
 23    max(case when cv = 2 then regexp_substr(comp, '\d+$')           end) as cnt_2,
 24    --
 25    max(case when cv = 3 then substr(comp, 1, instr(comp, ':') - 1) end) as comp_3,
 26    max(case when cv = 3 then regexp_substr(comp, '\d+$')           end) as cnt_3,
 27    --
 28    max(case when cv = 4 then substr(comp, 1, instr(comp, ':') - 1) end) as comp_4,
 29    max(case when cv = 4 then regexp_substr(comp, '\d+$')           end) as cnt_4
 30  from temp
 31  group by id
 32  order by id;

 ID COMP_1               CNT_1 COMP_2               CNT_2 COMP_3               CNT_3 COMP_4               CNT_4
--- -------------------- ----- -------------------- ----- -------------------- ----- -------------------- -----
  1 TD-2-2720A-NVE-C     2     TD-2-2720A-TPM-C     2     TD-PREM-NLSAS-01-PR  480   TD-ONTAP-NLSAS-01-PR 480
  2 TD-2-A220A-TPM-C     2     DD-FLASH-PREM-01-PR  115   DD-FLASH-ONTAP-01-PR 115
  5 TD-2-2650A-NVE-C     2     TD-2-2650A-TPM-C     2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instr(comp,':')
```

yields the first colon occurrence

```
instr(comp,':',1,2)
```

yields the second colon occurrence, and so forth

After that, its just math with combinations of INSTR on : and |

For example

```
substr(comp,2,instr(comp,':')-2)
```

for the first column before the colon

```
substr(comp,instr(comp,':')+1,instr(comp,'|')-instr(comp,':')-1)
```

for the first element after the colon and before the bar

and so forth.